# Why does xsd.exe generate string property for xs:integer?

Tags: c#, .net, xsd, xsd.exe

When I generate a c# class from a xsd schema with xsd.exe I find this behaivor a bit wierd.

My element:

```
<xs:element name="InvoiceNo" type="xs:integer"/>
```

is generated to:

```
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType="integer", Order=5)]
public string InvoiceNo
{
   ...
}
```

Why is that property not generated as an **int** instead of **string**?

Answer (score 73, accepted):

This behavior is [by design](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms950721.aspx):

> The `xs:integer` type is specified as a number with no upper or lower
>   bound on its size. For this reason, neither XML serialization nor
>   validation map it to the **System.Int32** type. Instead, XML serialization
>   maps the `xs:integer` to a string while validation maps it to the
>   **Decimal** type that is much larger than any of the integer types in the
>   .NET Framework

Use `xs:int`, which is a signed 32-bit integer, to have [Xsd.exe](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x6c1kb0s.aspx) map it to a [System.Int32](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.int32.aspx):

```
<xs:element name="InvoiceNo" type="xs:int" />
```

Here's a [detailed list](http://www.codalogic.com/lmx/xsd-overview.html#DefiningElementsPart1) of the data types defined in the XML Schema Definition standard.

Comment: Spot on. I was not aware of the difference between xs:int and xs:integer. I thought it was like int and Int32 in c#.

Comment: We have the issue now when trying to send valid data to TIBCO services. Of course TIBCO isn't going to change so we have, wonderful.

Comment: They definetly should use System.Numerics.BigInteger for that!