# Why does VS generate a string property for a xs:nonNegativeInteger attribute for WCF client?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, wcf, wsdl, type-conversion

I am building a WCF Client with VS2010. The web service we consume defines some data that it returns as xs:nonNegativeInteger. However VS2010, upon generation of the WCF client code, generates classes with properties of type string for these xs:nonNegativeInteger attributes.

I am wondering why that's the case and if and how I can tell VS2010 to adjust its mappings from xs:nonNegativeInteger to integer rather than string.

(I can't change the wsdl of the web service we consume... And I am also hesitant of simply changing the generated code in case we need to update the service reference, so some sort of data type mapping via a config would be ideal.)

Thanks all!

Example snippet of the WSDL we consume:

```
<xs:element minOccurs="0" name="blub" type="xs:nonNegativeInteger" />
```

Example snippet of the generated WCF client code:

```
<System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute(DataType:="nonNegativeInteger", Order:=0)>  _

Property blub() As String
```

Comment: [Same for all the xs:*integer types](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616040/why-does-xsd-exe-generate-string-property-for-xsinteger).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you've configured SvcUtil to use the `XmlSerializer` instead of the `DataContractSerializer`. MSDN says `XmlSerializer` will serialize the *xs:nonNegativeInteger* [to string](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlelementattribute.datatype.aspx) while `DataContractSerializer` will [serialize it to Int64](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733112.aspx) (search for 'nonNegativeInteger' in each page).

If you don't want to use `DataContractSerializer` for some reason, your best option is to take advantage of the generated proxy classes being `partial` classes and create a separate property (either `int` or `long`) to encapsulate the conversion logic without affecting how WCF serializes/deserializes that field.

BTW: if that `string` conversion really annoys you, [vote up this issue in CodePlex](http://xsd2code.codeplex.com/workitem/14731).

Comment: Thanks - It seems the integers are unrestricted, meaning the [only valid mapping](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9616162/314291) of the xs:*integer types would be to an arbitrarily large `BigInteger`