# Integer becomes a string when auto-generating classes with Visual Studio

Tags: c#, java, wsdl

I have a service reference to a java soap hosted web-service in my .NET project.
I let [Visual Studio](http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/visual-studio-2013) generate the reference classes.

I must however have missed something, because visual studio seems to fail on some elements.

This is a part of a WSDL for a class that the Java SOAP service exposes.

```
<xs:element name="A" type="xs:integer" nillable="false"/>
<xs:element name="B" type="xs:integer" nillable="false"/>
```

Looks perfectly fine to me, but in the auto-generated reference class by Visual Studio, these becomes string instead of `int`'s.

It's no problem to correct this however I'd like to understand why this happens.

So, my question is, why does this happen?

Comment: This answers my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616040/why-does-xsd-exe-generate-string-property-for-xsinteger

Comment: This answers my question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9616040/why-does-xsd-exe-generate-string-property-for-xsinteger